# Azure - Allow Site Access Without Microsoft Account

Tags: azure

I have a website that is set up and running fine on Azure. However I can only seem to access it if I log in to my own Microsoft account. Is there any way to just allow all http traffic without requiring authentication?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and elaborate? As it stands, it doesn't really make sense. For instance: What do you mean by "access" it? View the pages in a browser? Modify the content? Also, please explain how you deployed the website (web app? VM? cloud service?)

Answer (score 0):

Your site should be public accessible as long as you do not have any authentication setup.

e.g if your site is http://foo.azurewebsites.net, everyone should be able to visit your site.

if your question is to allow other people who do not have azure subscription to manage your site. you can assign Role permission to them see [Azure Role-based Access Control](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/) for details